# Different ListViews filtered from same ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, adapter

So I am working on a news application which has a Arraylist `TopNewsList` with all the news from all categories. Now I have a category specific list of news, so I want to use the same arraylist in the adapter for different `Listviews`, I want the adapter to filter the news based on category id I provide (I have it in the arraylist), the Arraylist is actually - `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` with id, news title, imageurl etc etc Note that I cannot use a copy , because there are fields like `read/unread` which should reflect across categories.

This is my ArrayList FYI

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

// adding each child node to HashMap key => value
map.put(TAG_CATEGORYID, id);
map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
map.put(TAG_DESCRIPTON, description);
map.put(TAG_CREATED, created);
map.put(TAG_IMAGE, image);
map.put(TAG_IMAGE2, image2);

// adding HashList to ArrayList
TopNewsList.add(map);
```

Comment: How you are using HashMap in your ArrayList, every news got his own HashMap or what?

Comment: @Jedil Every news got its own HashMap.

Comment: So how you store CategoryId in this hash map, and why you use hash map?

Comment: @Jedil Edited the question with more info.

Answer (score 1):

From design point of view you should make class/type `News` with this fields.
So you will get

```
class News
{
 String id;
 String title;
 // and so on
}
```

Then you will have `ArrayList<News> allNews` list of newses.

If you want to filter and get only some newses from the list just make another list

```
List<News> newsOfSportsCategory = ArrayList<News>();
for(int i=0;i< allNews.size();i++)
{
   if(allnews.get(i).id.equals("idOfSportsCat")
   {
      newsOfSportsCategory.add(allnews.get(i));
   }
}
```

You will get list with sport categories, and this is not copy because you are only holding references to objects that are also on allNews list.

Comment: I can do the copy thing with HashMap too - I think it doesnt make it better from design point of view. I dont want to do the copy because, there is another field like the `read/unread` which has to be synced across listviews.

Comment: You said that you cannot use copy. So this solution is not making any copies.
There is no constructor or `copy` method in my code. I'm only adding reference to object in my second list if news is from some category.